# UIScrollView contentInset vs viewport padding

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, padding, insets

I know about the `contentInset` on `UIScrollView`, however I'm trying to achieve something slightly different:  I want to have a "viewport" on the scrollview: essentially have all the content scroll within the scrollview but at all times have a blank padding on all sides.

In CSS terms, I want to achieve {height: 300px; padding: 10px; overflow: scroll;}

Is this possible and, if yes, how would I do that?

Comment: hm, not the answer, but maybe a solution. What if you remove 20px height, 20px width, add 10px top and 10px left? At least it is the same result as padding i think. :)

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs I'm not sure I follow.  what do you mean by "remove"?

Comment: scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,460); instead of scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

Comment: But that defeats the purpose.  The scrollview has a background with 0.8 alpha and is positioned on another UIView with its own background of 0.8 alpha - and the whole thing is over the screen, which has an image for the background.